# Automatic curve fitting to find order of an algorithm?

Tags: functions, regression, curves, floating-point

I'm a newbies in mathematics.

I'm looking for an automatic best curve fitting function to find the order of an algorithm.

I would like to know if it does exists a math library function that would take an array of points (cloud of point, whatever linear or n log n or n square , ...) as input and would return the best math function that would fits my points, with the best fitting coefficient.

Does a function that try each and every type of fitting functions: log n, n log n, ..., could exists? If yes, where can I find it?

I actually implemented a Linear Regression on my points results. It help to see the trend in regards to a straight line but its not accurate. It would have been really nice to have something more advanced that would be able to check against O(n), O(n log n), O(n square), O(n), ... to determine the exact order and find each factors (multiplying constant).

Note about usage: I've done a benchmark for many ConvexHull algorithms and some Smallest Enclosing circle algorithms. I want to have a confirmation of the order (performance) of each algorithm based on tests executed on 1000 to 10000000 points.

Thanks

Comment: are you looking for specifically polynomial fits? in what environment - C, Excel, MATLAB, Python, etc?

Comment: The "best function that fits your points" is usually not what you want. Please see [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting).

Comment: There is no "best" function that fits your points because each "best" function depends on the stated criteria of fitting, For example : least mean squares of errors, or of absolute errors, or relative errors, or ...  many others.

Comment: @gt6989b, I don't know if what I want exists. I want and a func that will analyse each and every possibilities, linear, polynomial, ..., and tell me which one of them is the better fit to my cloud of points.

Comment: @JJacquelin, I heard that squares of errors is the general accepted one. I think it would be fine to me. Is it  true that Squares of errors is the most used one in most general cases?

Comment: Yes, least squares fitting is of most common use : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html

Comment: @JJacquelin, Tthanks for confirmation.

Comment: Note that the run time when someone says an algorithm is logarithmic or quadratic or whatever is asymptotic. This means your fit for small $n$ (which may not be very small) may be quite different than what people say the algorithm is.

Comment: @Batman, You are right. In general, its hard to beat a good mathematical analysis to know what is the order of an algorithm. But when you want to know the real performance of your algorithm in life (I know tests is never like true life) nothing worth some good tests.  I currently tests with 10 000 000 and 100 000 000 of points. Which is a little higher than regular size for what my tested algorithms are used in real life. I think it could add very valuable information to algo efficiency.